# Getting incorrect value of sizeWithFont constrainedToSize with a custom font

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, sizewithfont

Im trying to get the size of a text, so that I can expand the height of a UITextView. I dont want it to have scroll.

Therefore I went and did this.

```
CGSize sizeText = label.frame.size;//[[event valueForKey:@"descr"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Titillium-Regular" size:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textFrame.size.width, 1000)];
```

And then set my UITextView with that new size. The problem is that the size, I only want the new height, is too small. Is either that with the custom font sizeWithFont doesn't work properly or that as I read in this [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1871967) the problems appear with the margins, but I tried his solution and i get the very same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,You need to put only `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]` in sizeWithFont instead of `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Titillium-Regular" size:15]`

You can set custom font for `UILabel` or `UITextView` whatever you want. after that you can find size of the text.

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Titillium-Regular" size:15]];
CGSize size1 = [[event valueForKey:@"descr"]sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textFrame.size.width, 1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: But that way I would be getting the size if of a System Font, not the size of the custom Font that Im going to use.